# reuse data for multiple examples in a tfrecord file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I try to use tfrecords for my tensorflow input pipline using the dataset api. My data consists of input images as well as reference images. My issue is that multiple input images have the same reference image thus I would like to somehow reuse the reference image data for multiple examples. Is there any way to achieve this?

**Update #1**
Input pipeline:

```
def input_fn(filenames, batch_size, isTraining=True):

def _batch_parse_example(example_proto):
        features = {
            'input_image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'input_shape': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'reference_image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'reference_shape': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }
        parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features, name='features')

        input_image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['input_image'], tf.float32)
        input_shape = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['input_shape'], tf.int32)
        input_image = tf.reshape(input_image, [input_shape[0], input_shape[1], 3])

        reference_image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['reference_image'], tf.float32)
        reference_shape = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['reference_shape'], tf.int32)
        reference_image = tf.reshape(reference_image, [reference_shape[0], reference_shape[1], 3])

        input_image = tf.expand_dims(input_image, 0)
        input_patches = tf.extract_image_patches(images=input_image, ksizes=[1, crop_size, crop_size, 1], strides=[1, crop_size, crop_size, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        input_patches = tf.reshape(input_patches, [-1, crop_size, crop_size, 3])
        reference_image = tf.expand_dims(reference_image, 0)
        reference_patches = tf.extract_image_patches(images=reference_image, ksizes=[1, crop_size, crop_size, 1], strides=[1, crop_size, crop_size, 1], rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        reference_patches = tf.reshape(reference_patches, [-1, crop_size, crop_size, 3])

        return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_patches, reference_patches))

def _map(input_image, reference_image):
    return {'input_image': input_image}, reference_image

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x).prefetch(1000), cycle_length=8)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(_batch_parse_example)
dataset = dataset.map(_map)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000)
dataset = dataset.repeat(None if isTraining else 1)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
batch_input_image, batch_reference_image = iterator.get_next()
return batch_input_image, batch_reference_image
```

Comment: Can you share what code you have for the input pipeline *without* sharing the reference images? It is possible to share the data between multiple examples (e.g. using a lookup table) but the details of doing so will depend on how your dataset is structured.

Comment: @mrry updated question with code snipped. Thanks!

Comment: @mrry any clues? sadly found no information about lookup tables in tfrecord files